# SOQL Query to get the users who are assigned to an assignment rule

Tags: soql

I have a question regarding assignment rules in salesforce. I have a set of users who are assigned to a particular assignment rule in lead object level. Is there any way to get those list of users through SOQL?

Below query gives which give me the assignment rule id, but it won't provide the related users on it.

```
SELECT Id FROM AssignmentRule WHERE Name = 'Lead Test Assignment' AND SobjectType = 'Lead'
```

Also, I read the [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_assignmentrule.htm) which is talking about Metadata api. Can I get this data through soql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this answer, there is no support in SOQL to find the entries within the AssignmentRule. The AssignmentRule object itself is only exposed so that integrations can query for a specific AssignmentRule they'd like to use in the AssignmentRuleHeader object. You would need to use the Metadata API to retrieve this information, as specified in the documentation.